# Selenium: How to prepend data to a text box or text Area

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Web driver. I have a Text Area where some text is written. Now How can I **prepend** some text/html in it or inserting a data at a specific location?

The following code **appends** it to the text Area/ Text Box

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("textBox/textArea")).sendKeys("abc");
```

ie. if the text area/ text box contains 123. The result of above would be **123abc**. But I want **abc123 or 12abc3**

PS: I am testing an "Email Reply" functionality. So as a user, when you reply to a mail, you do not do copy text, then clear all text then copy all the text back after writing the new text like below:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("textBox/textarea"));
String previousText = element.getAttribute("value");
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("abc" + previousText);
```

Please help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

...

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("textBox/textarea"));
element.sendKeys(Keys.HOME + "abc");
```

or may be for multiline text areas

```java
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.HOME);
element.sendKeys("abc");
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("textBox/textarea"));
 String previousText = element.getAttribute("value");
 element.clear();
 element.sendKeys("abc" + previousText);
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. But I do not want this. I am testing an "Email Reply"  functionality. So as a user, when you reply to a mail, you do not do copy text, then clear all text then copy all the text back after writing the new text

Comment: @bhuvan Does it really matter what happens in the process of getting to the end result? My supplied answer does exactly what you've asked for. If that's not what you want, modify your question to ask what it is you are really looking for.

Comment: @bhuvan, it doesn't matter, the end result is the same. Unless you have functionality depending on how the user enters the text, this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert text by Robot use.
Following my way.
I hope this helps you.

```java
public void runScript() {

    WebElement textarea = driver.findElement(By.id("textarea"));

    insert(textarea, "abc", 2);
}

public void insert(WebElement textElement, String insertText, int offset) {

    String currentText = textElement.getText();
    int len = currentText.length();
    if (len < offset) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("len(%d) < offset(%d)", len, offset));
    }
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.setAutoDelay(20);
    // On focus.
    textElement.click();
    // Move cursor for head.
    type(robot, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
    for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
        type(robot, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    }
    textElement.sendKeys(insertText);
}

public void type(Robot robot, int... keycodes) {
    for (int keycode : keycodes) {
        robot.keyPress(keycode);
    }
    for (int keycode : keycodes) {
        robot.keyRelease(keycode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of using `Robot` instead of just using `element.sendKeys`? What is that Robot class - is there any documentation? I could not find anything about it via google

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlContent = driver.find_element_by_id("wp-editor-area")
htmlContent.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.HOME)
htmlContent.sendKeys("The Content You WANT!")
```